# Getting undefined device.map error while displaying table react-native-table-component

Tags: react-native, react-native-table-component

I am a developing a React Native app.My requirement is to display data from API in the table format.I am using react-native-table-component.I am not able to traverse through an array to display data in the table.Below is my code:

TargetSetUpPage.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, Button, TextInput, ScrollView ,View} 
from "react-native";
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from "react-redux";
import * as authActions from "../../store/actions/auth";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native- 
 community/asyncstorage';
 import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table- 
 component';

  const TargetSetUpPage = (props) => {
  const [targetid, setTargetId] = React.useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const devices = [useSelector(state => 
  state.auth.availableDevice)];
  //console.log('The devices are: '+JSON.stringify(devices));

   if (typeof(devices) !== 'undefined' && devices != null) {
   console.log('Not Undefined and Not Null')
   } else {
   console.log('Undefined or Null')
   const devices = [useSelector(state => 
   state.auth.availableDevice)];

   }

   const tableHead = ['Target Id','Target Name']
   const tableRow = devices;
   console.log(devices); 
   const tableRows = (devices || []).map(item => ({ name: 
   item.name 
   }));


    useEffect(() => {
    const onScreenLoad = async() => {
    const useridfordevices = await 
     AsyncStorage.getItem("userDatauserid");
     const obj = JSON.parse(useridfordevices);
     const { userid } = obj;
     var userid1 = userid[0];
      await dispatch(authActions.getDeviceInfo(userid1))
     };
     onScreenLoad();
     },[dispatch]);

     return (
    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
    <View>
    {/* <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 
    '#c8e1ff'}}>
    <Row data={tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle= 
     {styles.text}/>
    <Rows data={tableRows} textStyle={styles.text}/>
    </Table> */}
     <FlatList
     data={devices}
     keyExtractor={item => item.TargetId}
      renderItem={itemData => (
     <View style={styles.card}>
   
    {/* <Text style={styles.text}>{itemData.item.TargetName} 
    </Text> */}
    <Button title={itemData.item.TargetName} onPress={()=>{}}/>
    </View>
     )}
     numColumns={2}
      />

     <Text style={styles.headingTitle}>
     Set your target and start running:
     
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.textstyle}>Target ID</Text>
    <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    value={targetid}
    onChangeText={(targetid) => setTargetId(targetid)}
    ></TextInput>
    <Button
     title="Add"
     // onPress = {() => }
    />
    </View> 
    </ScrollView>
     );
     };

     const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     input: {
     height: 40,
     width: "80%",
     margin: 12,
     borderWidth: 1,
     padding: 10,
     },
     headingTitle: {
     fontSize: 30,
      },
      textstyle: {
       paddingTop: 10,
       fontSize: 20,
        },
      compact: {
      flexDirection: "row",
       },});

      export default TargetSetUpPage;
```

After executing it is showing the below tableRow array in console:

Not Undefined and Not Null
Array [
undefined,
]

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.name')

But If I remove Table and display FlatList,I am able to display the list without any problem .I dont know what mistake I am doing in displaying the Table.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The error is telling you that devices = undefined at some point when you are calling devices.forEach. Probably state.auth.availableDevice is not defined for the entire lifetime of this component. So write your code to handle the cases where devices = undefined and where devices = some list.

Comment: Also this code `tableRow.push` shouldn't be in your render loop, it's going to run every time the component re-renders. Instead I think you want `const tableRow = devices.map(item => ({...}));`

Comment: I added the code to check the undefined, it shows that it is not undefined(Not Undefined and Not Null) : if (typeof(devices) !== 'undefined' && devices != null) { console.log('Not Undefined and Not Null')} else { console.log('Undefined or Null')  }.And after that I mapped the devices to tablerow as const tableRow = devices; which displays the following data: Array [Array [ Device {"TargetId":"jtgTargetDevice1","TargetName":"device_1",},
    Device { "TargetId": "jtgTargetDevice2","TargetName": "device_2", },],].Do you have any idea how to map const tableRow in return statement to display.

Comment: You'll have to update your question and show what error/problem you're seeing.

Comment: I have updated the code above .

Answer (score 1):

```
  // devices will be the same as auth.availableDevice in your redux
  // If auth.availableDevice is undefined at any point, like during boot
  // then devices will be undefined too
  const devices = useSelector(state => state.auth.availableDevice);

  // Let's write our map code so that it handles the case where devices is undefined
  const tableRows = (devices || []).map(item => ({ name: item.name }));
```

Comment: No matter whichever way we check for undefined, .map function is not picking items from the array.Its giving TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.name').I tried with item.TargetId also.Maybe there is problem with array itself .

Comment: print the array and show it here. that error is telling you that there are undefineds in your array like: `[{}, undefined, {}]`

Comment: I tried running the code as you said, the devices is showing undefined.But the <FlatList> is displaying correctly. I think the structure of array is not correct so it is not getting inserted into TableRows.And also I have updated the code above as per your changes.

Comment: You have to remove that second useselector, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help and support.I removed the second useselector but I was getting undefined error near data.map error.I added an Answer where I used DataTable and could get the table on screen trying after few days.

Answer (score 1):

I used DataTable from react-native-paper to get the table.Below is the code that renders data from API.

TargetSetUpPage.js:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {StyleSheet, Text, Button, TextInput, ScrollView, View, FlatList}
    from "react-native";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import * as authActions from "../../store/actions/auth";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import {DataTable} from 'react-native-paper';

const TargetSetUpPage = (props) => {
    const [targetid, setTargetId] = React.useState("");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const devices = useSelector(state => state.auth.availableDevice);

    useEffect(() => {
        const onScreenLoad = async () => {
            const useridfordevices = await
                AsyncStorage.getItem("userDatauserid");
            const obj = JSON.parse(useridfordevices);
            const {userid} = obj;
            var userid1 = userid[0];
            await dispatch(authActions.getDeviceInfo(userid1))
        };
        onScreenLoad();
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
            <View>
                <DataTable>
                    <DataTable.Header>
                        <DataTable.Title>
                            <Text>Target Id</Text>
                        </DataTable.Title>
                        <DataTable.Title>
                            <Text>Target Name</Text>
                        </DataTable.Title>
                    </DataTable.Header>
                    {devices.map((item, key) => (
                            <DataTable.Row>
                                <DataTable.Cell>{item.TargetId}</DataTable.Cell>
                                <DataTable.Cell>{item.TargetName}</DataTable.Cell>

                            </DataTable.Row>
                        )
                    )}
                </DataTable>
                <Text style={styles.headingTitle}>
                    Set your target and start running:
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.textstyle}>Target ID</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    value={targetid}
                    onChangeText={(targetid) => setTargetId(targetid)}
                ></TextInput>
                <Button title="Add"
                    // onPress = {() => }
                />
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        height: 40,
        width: "80%",
        margin: 12,
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 10,
    },
    headingTitle: {
        fontSize: 30,
    },
    textstyle: {
        paddingTop: 10,
        fontSize: 20,
    },
    compact: {
        flexDirection: "row",
    },
});

export default TargetSetUpPage;
```

which displays the table on the screen as shown below.

[image: Table from API data]